# docker-compose removes sibling container

Tags: linux, docker, docker-compose

I am using `docker-compose` along with the `docker-compose.yml` file as the final step of my ci/cd pipeline to create/re-create containers on a server.

Code example:

```
sudo docker-compose up --force-recreate --detach
sudo docker image prune -f --all --filter="label=is_image_disposable=true"
```

My goal is to deploy and **keep several containers** from the **same repo** but with a **different tags** on a **single server**.

The problem is that docker-compose seems to remove existing containers of my repo before it creates new ones, even tho the existing container has tag `:dev`, and the new one has tag `:v3`.

As an example: before `docker-compose` command has been executed I had a running container named

- `my_app_dev` container of the repo `hub/my.app:dev`,

and after the `docker-compose` command ran i have this

- `my_app_v3` container of the repo `hub/my.app:v3`.

What I do want to see in the end is both containers are up and running:

- `my_app_dev` container of the repo `hub/my.app:dev`
- `my_app_v3` container of the repo `hub/my.app:v3`

Can someone give me an idea how can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is expected behaviour. Compose works based on the concept of projects.
As long as the two compose operations are using the same project name, the configurations will override each other.

You can do what you want to some degree by using a unique project name for each compose up operation.

```
docker compose --project-name dev up 
docker compose --project-name v3 up
```

This leads to the containers being prefixed with that specific project name. i.e. `dev-app-1` and `v3-app-1`.

If they need to be all on the same network, you could create a network upfront and reference it as an external network under the default network key.

```yaml
networks:
  default:
    name: shared-network
    external: true
```